# What's the calculation order of the equation "i++ + ++i" in Java?

Tags: java, operators, increment, operator-precedence

Consider the snippet:

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
System.out.println(a + ++a);
System.out.println(b++ + ++b);
System.out.println(c++ + c);
```

The output is:

```
3
4
3
```

This is what I think is happening, but the output doesn't match up:

```
1. ++a -> +a -> 4 = 2 + 2
2. ++b -> +b -> 4 = 2 + 2
3. c -> +c -> 2 = 1 + 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unary post and pre-increment have higher precedence than addition:

1. `b = 1`, `b` is initialized to 1.
2. `b++`, `b`'s current value in the equation is 1, *then `b` is incremented*.
3. `++b`, `b` was incremented due to post-increment, so it's 2. Now it's incremented again due to pre-increment and its value in the equation is 3.
4. `1 + 3` is 4.

The thing is, pre-increment *increments the variable, then returns it* thus in `++1`, the value is incremented, then that is returned, and evaluates to 2. With post-increment, *the variable value is returned, then incremented*. Thus `1++` will evaluate to 1, then increment to 2 on later reference. So:

1. ```
   b++ + ++b
   ^^^
   post-increment, evaluates to 1
   ```
2. ```
   1 + ++b
       ^^^
       pre-increment, due to post-increment is 2, then pre-increments and evaluates to 3
   ```
3. ```
   1 + 3
   ^^^^^
   evaluates to 4
   ```

This applies to the first and third examples too. For `a + ++a`, `++a` has higher precedence. First, `a` is evaluated, which is 1 at this point, then `++a` is evaluated as it has higher precedence, where `a` is incremented, then the value returns and evaluates to 2. Then, addition is evaluated, which looks like this:

1. ```
   a + ++a
   ^
   nothing, evaluates to 1
   ```
2. ```
   1 + ++a
       ^^^
       pre-increment, evaluates to 2
   ```
3. ```
   1 + 2
   ^^^^^
   evaluates to 3
   ```

In the third example, `c++ + c`, `c` is post-incremented so it evaluates to 1, then increments. The last `c` is then 2 and looks like this:

1. ```
   c++ + c
   ^^^
   post-increment, evaluates to 1
   ```
2. ```
   1 + c
       ^
       nothing, due to post-increment is 2 and evaluates to 2
   ```
3. ```
   1 + 2
   ^^^^^
   evaluates to 3
   ```

Thus the output:

```
3
4
3
```

---

It should be noted that precedence does not dictate evaluation order. Precedence only changes parenthesization of an expression. Evaluation order in Java is **always left to right** as [ajb comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270811/whats-the-calculation-order-of-the-equation-i-i-in-java/45270853#comment77504751_45270853), unlike C/C++, see [JLS 15.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7).

Comment: In the third step, do you mean the value of `b` now is 2 then incremented to 3. What about the third example, `c` was 1 at first, then incremented, then `c` become 2, 1+2=3, right?

Comment: @caisil In the third case, `c++ + c`, `c++` would be evaluated, which would be 1 because of post-increment. Then `c` would be incremented to 2. The expression would essentially be `1 + 2` thus 3.

Comment: It should be noted that Java's definition requires that things be evaluated left-to-right, as demonstrated in this answer.  In some other languages, including C/C++, the order is left undefined, so an expression like b++ + ++b could have different results using different compilers.

Answer (score 2):

As we know, `x++` and `++x` do the same thing, in slightly different ways. `x++` returns that value and then increments. `++x` increments the value and then returns it.

Good logic, but you forgot some things.

In your first you take `a`, which is 1, and add it to `++a`. The ++ in the front causes it to increment from one to two, and the equation is now `1 + 2`. That's three.

You take `b++`. `b` was a 1 before, and since you put the ++ in the back, it gives the initial value of 1 to the rest of the equation and afterwards increments the variable to 2. But you forgot that even though the value we got from `b++` is 1, in the memory, `b` is now 2. Since b is 2, the next part, `++b` returns 3.

The same mistake happens in the 3rd part. `c` returns 1, then increments to two. Then you add 1 to `c`, which is now two since you incremented it, and you get 3.

So here's what happened:

a: `1 + 2 = 3`

b: `1 + 3 = 4`

c: `1 + 2 = 3`

Answer (score 1):

`a++` evaluates to a, then increments a. `++a` first increments a, then returns a.

From the operator precedence chart at http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/, you can see that addition works from left to right.

Going through each of your examples, where each variable starts at 1:

`a + ++a`: `a` gets added to `a` incremented by 1. This gives us 1+2 (3).

`b++ + ++b`: `b` *before* it's incremented gets added to `b` after it was incremented by `b++` and after it's incremented by `++b`. This gives us 1+3 (4).

`c++ + c`: `c` before it's incremented gets added to `c` after being incremented, giving 1+2 (3).